# Android button text alignment not working

Tags: android, button, alignment

So I am developing an android application, I have done this before and never before have I encountered this problem.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/LoginFormLoginBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_buttons"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LoginFormPasskey" />
```

So  as you can see fairly straight forward, only thing the text should be centered, which it was before but suddenly without any code changes its now aligned slightly to the right. I have no idea why.

I searched around on stackoverflow and did not find any such bug raised by anyone.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baDzp.png) this is how it looks

Comment: did you try giving gravity="centre" to button? What you're experiencing shouldn't happen normally.

Comment: I did try that, no change in the situation, what I found instead was the margins that i set, were being applied to the background resources but the text was only center aligned, for android:layout_width="match_parent"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the layout width to 0dp instead

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/LoginFormLoginBtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_buttons"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LoginFormPasskey" />
```

Comment: Wow, that did it, can you explain as to why setting the width 0dp centers the text? Does this behavior transcend to other layout elements as well?

Comment: match_parent is invalid when the parent is a ConstraintLayout, so you may get funky results. If you want to constrain the width to fill the available space, you have to use 0dp.